# Hidden Tab bar view prevents touches

Tags: iphone

I have a hidden tab bar but I am finding that the area of the view that is where the tab bar would have been does not receive touch events. The tab bar is hidden due to setting hidesBottomBarWhenPushed.
Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got around the problem by adding my view as a sub view of myViewController.tabBarController.view so that it appears on top of the tab bar. Works ok now

Answer (score 0):

Set the .frame property to CGRectZero when you're hiding it, thus making it take up no space.  I had this problem and as you say, the objects "underneath" your invisible control can't receive touch events!

Comment: Sounds promising. How were you hiding it? I set myController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES. Where did you set the frame property? on one of the subviews of the tabBarController.view?